# Liferay foreach loop backwards

Tags: foreach, liferay, velocity

Is it possible to get elements in **reverse order**.

So right now the typical velocity foreach goes like this:

```
<ol style="list-style: decimal!important;">
    #foreach ($i in $item.siblings)
        <li>$i.data</li>
    #end
</ol>
```

> Output:
>
> 1. One
> 2. Two
> 3. Three
> 4. Four

But I would like to get the output reverse, like:

> 1. Four
> 2. Three
> 3. Two
> 4. One

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $item.siblings is implementation of List you can try

```
<ol style="list-style: decimal!important;">
    #set($c = $item.siblings.size())
    #foreach ($i in $item.siblings)
        #set($c = $c - 1)
        #set($sibling = $item.siblings.get($c))
        <li>$sibling.data</li>
    #end
</ol>
```

Comment: That's not very efficient, why not:

    `#foreach ($i in [$item.siblings.size()..0])
      #set ($sibling = $item.siblings.get($i))
    #end`

Comment: Idea is very good, but for this snippet to work, it must be changed to #foreach ($i in [$mathTool.sub($item.siblings.size(),1)..0]) #set ($sibling = $item.siblings.get($i)) #end